# Is it possible to put a schedule on raw reaction add? [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord.py

I did an on raw reaction add where my bot will count all the reactions [ex. a, b, c] and if one of them reaches 10 it will then send the result in a log channel.

Is it possible to add a timer for this? I want my bot to count the reaction weekly instead of sending the result when one of the reaction reaches 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the datetime library and then count 7 days from the last time you sent it.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html